# ACPI errors at boot with kernel 4.17.2 and 4.16

Tags: boot, acpi

I am having these errors/warnings everytime I boot elementaryos with kernel 4.16 or kernel 4.17.2 on a ideapad 110-15isk with a i3 6006u and no dedicated graphics.

Does someone know how to fix them?

[image: Errors/Warnings at boot]

Answer (score 0):

First two warnings are pretty harmless.
(I have them almost a year now,on same v110-15isk like you).
As for the rest,Im not sure.
I do have Arch with 4.17 installed alongside eOS,and never saw such warnings.

It could be due to Ubuntu kernel-patches.

I wouldnt recommend running vanilla mainland kernel on any Ubuntu based distro.

If it means something,give HWE-edge kernel a shoot.
It boosted performance and battery life for me.